# Proper rounded border around fieldset and legend

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a border around a fieldset and its legend, without having the bottom part of this border on the legend.

Here's the default behavior:

```css
fieldset {
  border:  1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
}
legend {
  border:  1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Legend</legend>
</fieldset>
```

I would like the legend to be "part of the fieldset", like this:

[image]

I tried many tricks, playing with `border-bottom` and `box-shadow` without success.
Does anyone knows a way to achieve this properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading all answers, I came to a satisfying solution, without any shift, nor additional markup:

```css
fieldset {
  border:  1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
}
legend {
  position: relative;
  border:  1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
legend:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  height: 13px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Legend</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you add an inner `<span>` to the legend, you can acheive this effect with a little css hackery.

```css
fieldset {
  border:  1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
legend {
  border:  1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  padding: 0 18px;
  position:relative;
  top: -10px;
}
legend span {
  position:relative;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend><span>Legend</span></legend>
</fieldset>
```

If you can't add the inner span, you can get a similar effect, but it's not quite as perfect.

```css
fieldset {
  border:  1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
legend {
  border:  1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  padding: 8px 18px 0;
  position:relative;
  top: -14px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Legend</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution idea with no added markup.  Use a pseudo element with the same background color as the legend and fieldset to hide the bottom portion of the legend.

Here's a sample.  Tweak as needed.

```css
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
legend {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
legend::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 7px;
  right: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Legend</legend>
</fieldset>
```